# Rotational kinematics with a pulley of finite mass

Tags: rotational-kinematics

The pulley is with a finite mass. The two blocks, hence, have different tensions exerted on the rope. My question is do the two blocks have the same acceleration ?
I would like a reason for the same.

[image]

Comment: The answer depends on the kinematics of the system, which is quite unclear from your illustration. As a matter of fact, it looks like the vertical and horizontal rope are at different distances from the center of rotation of the roller, noting, also, that it's not clear where that center of rotation is. Depending on the answers to these questions, the two masses may well have different accelerations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the rope is inextensible then one end of the rope must have the same magnitude of acceleration as the other end of the rope.
If that was not the case the distance between the two ends of the rope would change.
So the magnitude of the acceleration of the objects attached to the ends of the rope must be the same.

Answer (score 0):

Yes the blocks will have the same acceleration . The mass of the pulley will be balanced by the Normal force of the ground as well as the resultant Tension forces of the rope . There will be no effect of gravitational force of the pulley on the blocks .